# What should I use instead of radio buttons in a touch interface?

Tags: user-interface, touch

i'm adapting an existing web application to use with a touch scrren on a kiosk. I have two radio buttons in the normal web interface that of course are not usable.

What's the best thing to use instead of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radio buttons should be quite usable in a touch interface. After all, they are specifically modeled on a real-world "touch" interface.

If your real problem is "My radio buttons are too small to touch with the particular setup I have here", and you can't convince your device to scale things up (e.g. by specifying a width and height in CSS), your best bet would probably be to emulate radio buttons using Javascript and your own images, and a hidden form field.

Comment: In the real world unfurtunatly we still have 3 years old kiosks with orrible touch control!Thx for the advice, the image idea looks good!

Answer (score -2):

You should use a segmented button instead of the radio buttons as they provide a bigger surface to tap on.